# What type of push ups benefit muscle up?

Tags: push-ups, muscle-ups

I want to do muscle up. I can do 14 pull ups and I can get my elbow above the bar in to the muscle up position but when it comes to pushing down and completing the muscle up I don't have the required strength.

So I want to know what type of push up exercises I can do so I can push down something(complete the muscle up) more easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The muscle up could be viewed as a 3 steps exercise:

1. Pull up
2. Transition (the hardest part)
3. Push down or sometimes called dip

It seems you have a problem with the last step. The exercise I recommend the most is [straight bar dips](https://youtu.be/Z8C3d9Gcdk0?t=56). In the beginning you might not be able to go that deep but don't fret about it. After a while you will be able to.

In general, it would also help doing the muscle up in reverse but slowly.

To answer the question at hand: I don't think that push-ups would effectively help you. The closest I could think of are [tiger bend push-ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN7e-APdfhc) in combination with close or diamond push-ups.

Answer (score 10):

You need to do dips. Start with [dips on parallel bars](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWTriDip.html) and progress to ring dips.

Push-ups aren't specific practice for the pushing motion of the muscle-up.

Comment: The problem is there isn't a place at my house to dips the correct way (everything is either uncomfortable or loose or something). So that is why I am looking for a push up type to strengthen those muscles.

A friend told me to put my hands above my head in diamond shape and do push ups like that to increase muscle up strength but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @demirb This is a good chance to develop your workout-equipment-discovery skills. Is there a park nearby? A gym? Could you scrounge up a sturdy table and keep it in the basement? Do you have any metal folding chairs?

Comment: @demirb Also, is your friend talking about superman pushups or handstand pushups? The latter I could see as helping a bit.

Comment: If you can get your body above the bar where you do pull ups (without doing a muscle up), you can do dips there.  Start at the top position and work on increasing your range of motion over time.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Whoops. Yeah, that's the best option. Good catch.

Comment: @demirb I am nearly sure you could try the corner dip: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=y4mCllu5Qps

Comment: @DaveLiepmann workout-equipment-discovery skills was the solution. I found an old desk and moved it close to mine, so now I can do dips between them :)
My friend was talking about superman pushups. But now I have equipment to do dips :)
Thanks guys

Comment: You could try "corner dips" too: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/y4mCllu5Qps/hqdefault.jpg